# Encrypted file with CMD Command Cipher is no longer encrypted when send by mail

Tags: encryption, cmd

I want to use the cmd prompt `cipher` so that other users who use a shared directory can't see the data in the encrypted file.
To encrypt a file I use this line:

```
cipher /e test.txt /a
```

The file `test.txt` appears now with a little lock. I think that the file is now encrypted and only I'm able to read the file.

When I attach the file to an email the encryption is no longer active. The lock is gone and others can read the file.

Is this behavior normal and will this happen if others email my file? I've read some articles on that but couldn't find an answer. Only some people with the same question, like in the comments of this [article](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/cipher-command-line-tool-windows).

Comment: Your question is asking about the behavior of a specific software utility, and is therefore off topic on this site. Here we provided assistance for a specific issue with your provided programming code. _Also taking account of some of your comments, it is also off topic to request software recommendations too!_

Comment: I try to find the comment where I ask for software recommendations. I can only find one where I said "without additional program".  Which is the exact opposite of asking for software recommendations. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert with cipher, but from what I found is that this file is just encrypted on the locale file system. So if you have multiple users on your OS the file can just decrypted by the users. see cipher /C in the folder where the encrypted file is located.

in the explorer the file has not a little yellow lock on its symbol, but will be decrypted if you access it. So if you copy the file to another location on you pc the file is still encrypted. But if you transfer it to an e-mail program the file gets decrypted.

If you want mail encryption I defenetly recommend gpg for this.
If you want some other encryption you can use a Program like TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt/(7Zip, has also some kind of encryption)/cryptomator/boxcryptor/...

Comment: Do you know other encryption technologies without additional program?

Comment: no sorry, but technically the cipher command is also an additional program.

Comment: That's right. But it comes with the most Windows installations.

Comment: maybe take a portable version of this tool and transfer it with the data? or use zip with aes ecryption it is also on most windows(es) installed